# High query execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, orm, mybatis

```
SELECT T.xhrs, T.eq_id, mt.CATEGORY, mt.MODEL_NAME,
       ROUND((SUM (T.TOT_AVAIL_TIME-T.maintenance_TIME) / SUM(T.TOT_AVAIL_TIME))*100) AVAILABILITY,
       ROUND((SUM(UTIL_TIME) / nullif(SUM(T.TOT_AVAIL_TIME-T.maintenance_TIME ),0) )*100) UTILIZATION,
       ROUND(SUM(T.failedcmds)/
       SUM(T.total_failedcmds),2)*100 failedcmds,
       AVG(MAX_QL) MAX_QL,
       AVG(AVG_QL) avg_ql
FROM db1 T,
     db2 mt
WHERE T.eq_model = mt.eq_model
  and TOT_AVAIL_TIME != 0
  AND TOT_AVAIL_TIME  IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.xhrs, T.eq_id, mt.CATEGORY, mt.MODEL_NAME
```

This query returns 2550 records and takes 12-15 s to run in SQL Developer and in mybatis it takes 30-35 secs. Is there any thing wrong with existing query? Is there any way to optimize above query and bring down the execution time to <5 secs in sql developer and <15 secs in ORM?

Explain Plan

[image]

Comment: Post the explain plan

Comment: `OPERATION    OBJECT_NAME    CARDINALITY    COST 
  SELECT STATEMENT 
       2550    58 
     
  HASH 
       2550    58 
          
  HASH JOIN 
       2550    9 
               
  Access Predicates 
                    
  T.EQ_MODEL=MT.EQ_MODEL 
               
  TABLE ACCESS 
  DB_SYS_KEY_EQ_MST    12    3 
               
  TABLE ACCESS 
  DB_SYS_AGGR_TAB    2550    6 
                    
  Filter Predicates 
                         
  AND 
                              
  TOT_AVAIL_TIME<>0 
                              
  TOT_AVAIL_TIME IS NOT NULL `

Comment: Can you please edit your question, adding the explain plan in a more readable format?

Comment: @SiddP Please edit your question with that information.  The lack of formatting options in the comment section makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: sorry edited in the q's itself.

Comment: @SiddP Is the table indexed? Indexing T on TOT_AVAIL_TIME should help tremendously

Comment: @PetterFriberg Sure will do once I find any answer fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me bring up a few points for us to think about performance.

The matter of fact is that "MyBatis or any other ORM is going to be slower than native SQL execution". Some of the reasons for this fact are:

- R1. It is clear that MyBatis adds overhead to database calls. You gain flexibility, maintenance and encapsulation but you lose in performance.
- R2. In most cases, MyBatis is going to parse the ResultSet to Java objects, this adds additional overhead. SQL Clients can work straight with cursors which are faster but in a long run it may be harder to maintain.
- R3. In most cases, MyBatis is going to create a transaction for you, this adds additional overhead.
- R4. In most cases, MyBatis is going to create and manage a cache for you, this adds additional overhead for the fist select but speed up the process for the next selects.
- R5. MyBatis can also help you with lazy loading and other data retrieval strategies.
  -R6. We should compare MyBatis executions against JDBC executions. Instead of comparing MyBatis against a SQL Client Tool (such as SQL Developer) because there are variables which can obscure your results. Example, they may not fetch all rows at once.

That being said, MyBatis may give you flexibility, better maintenance, an easy way to handle transact, easy way to parse tables to Java objects but it you take some performance from you.

So, if you want to speed up your queries there are a few things you should consider. See [MyBatis Documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html):

- C1. Use fetchSize in your queries.
- C2. Use cache wisely, see what kind of caching it is needed, in some cases it make sense to do not use cache at all. Example: `<select ... useCache="false">`
- C3. Be aware of the "N+1 Selects Problem". The documentation has some insights about this characteristic of many ORMs.
- C4. Try to use a lightweight transactionManager such as "JDBC", keep in mind that aspect oriented transactions (such as in Spring @Transactional) will add a little bit more of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Add index on `eq_model` column and check

---

Please try with this query only i combined the where condition on `TOT_AVAIL_TIM`

```
SELECT T.xhrs, T.eq_id, mt.CATEGORY, mt.MODEL_NAME,
       ROUND((SUM (T.TOT_AVAIL_TIME-T.maintenance_TIME) / SUM(T.TOT_AVAIL_TIME))*100) AVAILABILITY,
       ROUND((SUM(UTIL_TIME) / nullif(SUM(T.TOT_AVAIL_TIME-T.maintenance_TIME ),0) )*100) UTILIZATION,
       ROUND(SUM(T.failedcmds)/
       SUM(T.total_failedcmds),2)*100 failedcmds,
       AVG(MAX_QL) MAX_QL,
       AVG(AVG_QL) avg_ql
FROM db1 T,
     db2 mt
WHERE T.eq_model = mt.eq_model
  AND (TOT_AVAIL_TIME != 0 AND TOT_AVAIL_TIME  IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY T.xhrs, T.eq_id, mt.CATEGORY, mt.MODEL_NAME
```

Comment: Dont have the access to change in db I guess you would need to create index on column.

Comment: yet using indexing it takes almost same time as the query uses almost 98% of total records.

Comment: Well still the cost is 58 and there is no change in exec time

Answer (score 0):

If the tables aren't indexed properly yet, you could get the most out of indexing `T` by `TOT_AVAIL_TIME` and `T.eq_model` and indexing `mt` by `mt.eq_model`

Comment: No indexes are not used. Will check with my db team and will let you know if that helps. Thanks

Comment: @SiddP Indexes are always useful, but in this particular case they will most likely speed up the entire thing by more then rewriting your query can.

Comment: essentially indexing the TOT AVAIL TIME would almost completly remove the load on the WHERE operations here, since the SQL server could optimize checking for that away for all rows beyond the 0 and NULL index points. Indexing by the two JOIN statement columns will also tremendously speed up the actual join

Comment: Sure will check that. Thanks

Comment: yet using indexing it takes almost same time as the query uses almost 98% of total records.

Comment: @SiddP Try indexing every field you use in the where, select and group by instructions, in that order

Answer (score 0):

Put `T.eq_model` and `T.TOT_AVAIL_TIME` in one index (in this order).

Note: as you also check for NULL-ness of `TOT_AVAIL_TIME`, I assume it can be NULL by column definition. If you index it in a simple index, NULL-s are not indexed, and a `TOT_AVAIL_TIME IS NOT NULL` won't use the index later. So either combine it with `eq_model`, or remove that filter and change the column to `NOT NULL`.

I used this workaround on nullable columns on JIRA: `(PROJECT_CAN_HAS_NULL ASC, '1')`.

Comment: yet using indexing it takes almost same time as the query uses almost 98% of total records.